# Как вернуть переменную из вызова PL/SQL блока?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Вызываю PL/SQL блок так:

```
sql = """
DECLARE
    num NUMBER := 1;
    res NUMBER;
BEGIN
    res := num + 1;
END;
"""
try:
    cursor.execute(sql) 
    print ("PL/SQL successfully executed.")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print (e)
```

Этот код выполняется без проблем.

А как вернуть результат из вызова в переменнную Python?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Return variable from cx_Oracle PL/SQL call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18267935) от участника [@Michael Hecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946052/michael-hecht)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/18267935

Answer (score 3):

В основном есть [две возможности](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html):

1. Воспользоваться переменными связывания:

   ```
   sql = """
   DECLARE
       num NUMBER := :val;
       res NUMBER;
   BEGIN
       :res := num + 1;
   END;
   """
   res = cursor.var (int)
   cursor.execute(sql, val=1, res=res)
   print (f"result is {res.getvalue()}")

   result is 2
   ```
2. Преобразовать анонимный блок в функцию или процедуру (первый предпочтительней):

   ```
   create or replace function func (i int) return int is 
   begin
       return (i*2);
   end;
   /
   create or replace procedure proc (i int, res out int) is 
   begin
       res := (i*2);
   end;
   /
   ```

   Вызов:

   ```
   res = cursor.callfunc ('func', int, (1,))
   print (f"result is {res}")

   res = cursor.var (int)
   cursor.callproc ('proc', [1, res])
   print (f"result is {res.getvalue()}")

   result is 2
   result is 2
   ```